Unity Slider Value not changing
I'm making a game that is supposed to be run in 2 instances. The first instance is used to open Scene 1, (the Controller screen), which has this script attached to an object:
public void UpdateTimer()
{
    if (timerOn)
    {
        timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("TimeLeft", timeLeft);
    }
    
    if(timeLeft <= 0)
    {
        timerOn = false;
        timeLeft = 10f;
    }
}

When a button is pressed, the bool timerOn is set to true and the float timeLeft is set to 10f.
Then a script in the second instance runs this script on a Slider object:
void Update()
{
    timer.value = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("TimeLeft", 0);
}

This works when the second instance has Scene 2 open (PartOneOfGame) and the timer goes down correctly. The issue shows up when I load Scene 3 (PartTwoOfGame) (Done with a button with the LoadScene function), where no matter how I test it, the value of the Slider component cannot be changed, both by script or in the Unity Editor. Those are separate Slider objects that have the same script attached to them.
I tried to place a part of the script in the Slider Object Script:
timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime; PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("TimeLeft", timeLeft);
which fixed the issue temporarily, but when removed it didn't work.
I tested both in builds and in the Editor, which had the same results.
Other attempts include: Copying the scene where it works, changing stuff to fit the second scene (minor changes), redoing the whole canvas by hand, and adding stuff back in the 3rd scene (did nothing, the slider kept changing its value back to max value, not even debug.log detected me trying to change it), talking to myself (no new ideas), talking to other human beings (no new ideas), settings the starting value to 4.76 (it instantly went to max value and stayed that way).
I think that's all of my attempts.
The way I want it to work is:
When the button is pressed, the timer starts counting down from 10 with the Slider representing the amount of time left, when it hits 0 the timer stops and goes back to 10.
I think it has something to do with the slider, but I am now desperate for a solution. What could be causing the issue and how do I fix it??

I'm not saying this is an xy-problem, because these points don't seem to be your problems, but: 1. You shouldn't use sliders to represent progress bars. You use an image set to "filled". 2. You shouldn't write nor read the PlayerPrefs all the time. It's probably best to not use them at all, but that's a different story. Anyways, if this is a value that you never use outside of the application, just use a variable to store the value?

Id also suggest you dont seem to save the preferences, so.. maybe the values always 0

Thank you for your suggestions. Saving the preferences couldn't have been the issue, because:
a) I added it and it didnt fix anything
b) it worked without it on scene 2
Using a variable won't do because if my testing is to be belived variables do not transfer between instances (I made a button object, added a script that set it's text to:
buttonText.text = " " + number;
Then added IncreaseNumber() function which was basically
number++;
and added it to the button. When two instances of the build were opened the int was not shared between them.

I found a solution which was: create a separate script for the scene 3 timer, copy and paste the previous one and add it onto the scene 3 timer which worked and fixed everything. I belive the issue was connected to the scene reading playerprefs or not updating correctly but since this works it works. Tank you for your suggestions.
